# Codeigniter image rotate when image resize

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an image with the dimension of (W-3000 X H-4000). When i upload it and resize, it always show like landscape mode, mean new dimension is w-1067 X h-800. I want to create this picture either 800X600 for landscape or 600X800 for portrait. Here is my code:

```
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|gif|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '5000';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    //check if a file is being uploaded
    if(strlen($_FILES["testimg"]["name"])>0){

        if ( !$this->upload->do_upload("testimg"))//Check if upload is unsuccessful
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            print_r($errors);
        }
        else
        {

            $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
            $config['source_image'] = $this->upload->upload_path.$this->upload->file_name;
            $config['width'] = '1';
            $config['height'] = '800';
            $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
            $config['master_dim'] = 'height';
            $this->load->library('image_lib',$config); 

            if (!$this->image_lib->resize()){  
                echo "error";
            }else{
                echo "success";
            }
       }      
   }
```

In my code height is always 800px in size. It is ok for 3000X4000 dimension image. But what about when i use 4000X3000 dimension image? Can any one help me about this issue? Thanks

Comment: use getimagesize()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks @Rpojka for your answer. But I fixed it with **exif_read_data()** . Here is my code:

```
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|gif|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '6048';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    //check if a file is being uploaded
    if(strlen($_FILES["testimg"]["name"])>0){

        if ( !$this->upload->do_upload("testimg"))//Check if upload is unsuccessful
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            print_r($errors);
        }
        else
        {

            $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
            $config['source_image'] = $this->upload->upload_path.$this->upload->file_name;
            $filename = $_FILES['testimg']['tmp_name'];


            $imgdata=exif_read_data($this->upload->upload_path.$this->upload->file_name, 'IFD0');


            list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
            if ($width >= $height){
                $config['width'] = 800;
            }
            else{
                $config['height'] = 800;
            }
            $config['master_dim'] = 'auto';


            $this->load->library('image_lib',$config); 

            if (!$this->image_lib->resize()){  
                echo "error";
            }else{

                $this->image_lib->clear();
                $config=array();

                $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
                $config['source_image'] = $this->upload->upload_path.$this->upload->file_name;


                switch($imgdata['Orientation']) {
                    case 3:
                        $config['rotation_angle']='180';
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        $config['rotation_angle']='270';
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        $config['rotation_angle']='90';
                        break;
                }

                $this->image_lib->initialize($config); 
                $this->image_lib->rotate();

            }
       }      
   }
```

**Here is the exif orientation chart**

```
 1        2       3      4         5            6           7          8

888888  888888      88  88      8888888888  88                  88  8888888888
88          88      88  88      88  88      88  88          88  88      88  88
8888      8888    8888  8888    88          8888888888  8888888888          88
88          88      88  88
88          88  888888  888888
```

Comment: Nice solution. Just be awware of file type because of file type and it would be good to handle it with something like `if (exif_imagetype('image.gif') == IMAGETYPE_JPEG OR  exif_imagetype('image.gif') == IMAGETYPE_TIFF_II OR  exif_imagetype('image.gif') == IMAGETYPE_TIFF_MM) {
    //rest of code
} else {//handle exception}`

Comment: Thanks for your info :)

Comment: No problem, I found it in [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php). Good work for you though.

Comment: I had the same problem when upload from mobile devices.  I used your example to fix my issue.  thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
$filename = $_FILES['testing']['tmp_name'];
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);

if ($width >= $height)
{
    $config['width'] = 800;
    $config['master_dim'] = 'width';
}
else
{
    $config['height'] = 800;
    $config['master_dim'] = 'height';
}
```

Even shorter, you can use 'auto' parameter for `master_dim` that will determine which value is greater - width or height.

```
$filename = $_FILES['testing']['tmp_name'];
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);

if ($width >= $height)
{
    $config['width'] = 800;
}
else
{
    $config['height'] = 800;
}

$config['master_dim'] = 'auto';
```

Comment: I have tried it with 2448X3264 dimension image. When I resize, it show 800X600 image. But the resized image is rotated. I think I should use exif.